# Which database to use in a C# WPF app stored in a shared directory?

Tags: c#, database, wpf

I need to make an C# WPF app which would be stored in a shared directory, which is accessible by several users in a company, it's a local network. This app should have a database to read/write some information. So I was wondering which database to use and I'm not allowed to connect to database via web, it must be something inside that local network. I need to store only some strings and values in database. Thank you!

Comment: Is there some database inside your network, that you might be able to use? Maybe ask IT for that

Comment: I could ask them, though, I'm not sure. I'm not working in that company, I need to develop app for them. I've read about SQLite a bit, but I'm not sure if it's a good option.

Comment: for the database Ideally you will need a database server. Ask your IT colleges for that, because probably you already have one. in such scenario just ask them to create a new DB/tables and go for it. if you dont have any. you will need a database server, either in your company (which means a pc 24/7 running) or in the cloud. for development purposes ideally you will install a database in your pc, but only for development, production shoudl be in other pc/cloud. If you are the only one in IT, you will need to expose the scenario to your boss because is money involved yes or yes.

Comment: I'm not allowed to use cloud. So the best option is to ask company IT sector I think.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Express is free and your best option, but it might take some learning on your part. Microsoft's recommended approach is Entity Framework, but from my own experience that will add more to the learning curve time.

Since you are using C#, I just posted a video yesterday that shows you how to create a SQL Server Express database and 100% stored procedure powered data-tier using DataTier.Net

https://youtu.be/sowTLLeAfm8

This video is for Dot Net Core & Blazor, but most of the other videos on my channel are for Windows Forms, so not much different than WPF.

Here is the project home on Git Hub
https://github.com/DataJuggler/DataTier.Net

[image]

DataTier.Net is an Entity Framework alternative that creates 100% stored procedure powered data-tiers for .Net Framework and now Dot Net Core 3.0 projects.

End Plug, my project is free so please forgive me if I appear to be a spammer. I am not selling flip phones or aluminum siding.

Contact me if you have any questions.

www.datajuggler.com